# SharePoint designer workflow not sending duplicate emails

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have 2 Sharepoint sites which are mirror of each other, when i add a item in the old site it is added to new one and vice versa, i have a workflow set up on a list(in both the sites) which triggered an email when a item is created.
But when i add a item i recieve only 1 email instaed of 2 email(1 from old and other from the mirror site).
let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check workflow settings (Creating a new item will start this workflow should be checked). View Internal status for workflow for items on site where you have problems with workflow. For debugging purposes add logging (writing messages to workflow history).